# Error after (trying to) recording usb microphone with alsa record

Tags: audio, alsa

I'm setting up [alexa-pi](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-avs-sample-app/wiki/Raspberry-Pi) and everything was going smoothly until the final step which is running a wake word engine. I'm keep getting " 'pcm' failed." error. I've read somewhere that in order to this to work first I need to make sure that `arecord -d 10 -f S16_LE -r 16000 test.wav` command would record my voice input, however when I try to run it I get

```
arecord: main:722: audio open error: No such file or directory
```

Here's some of my outputs

```
~$ cat /proc/asound/modules 
 0 snd_bcm2835
 1 snd_usb_audio

~$ arecord -l
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 1: Mic122033996 [Wireless Mic #122033996], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Also I had to put this .conf file in `/etc/modprobe.d/` so alsa can see my microphone (it couldn't before)

```
# This sets the index value of the cards but doesn't reorder.
options snd_usb_audio index=1
options snd_bcm2835 index=0

# Does the reordering.
options snd slots=snd_bcm2835,snd_usb_audio
```

and here's whats wake word engine throws:

```
$ ./wakeWordAgent -e sensory
INFO:main: Starting Wake Word Agent
INFO:WakeWordAgent: State set to IDLE(2)
INFO:Initializing Sensory library | library name: TrulyHandsfree | library version: 5.0.0-avs.1 | model file: ../ext/resources/spot-alexa-rpi.snsr
WARNING:Library expires on: License expires on 28 Apr 2017 00:00:00 GMT
wakeWordAgent: pcm.c:694: snd_pcm_close: Assertion `pcm' failed.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've solved my problem replacing ~/.asoundrc file with this content

```
pcm.!default { type asym playback.pcm { type plug slave.pcm "hw:0" } capture.pcm { type plug slave.pcm "hw:1" } }
```

Comment: I would suggest you instead just specify the device in the arecord command. Setting hot-pluggable devices as default in the asound file will cause you trouble later. From experience.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command:

```
arecord -D hw:1,0 -d 10 -f S16_LE -r 22050 test.wav
```

`-D` sets the device specifically, otherwise it may be trying to use a non existant input device on `hw:0`.

You can also set your soundcard index for `snd_usb_audio` to `index=0` and the `snd_bcm2835` to `index=1` but specifying the device in the command is more reliable.

Further, though maybe not required for this, make sure you have this line in your `/boot/config.txt`

```
dtparam=audio=on
```

Comment: Thanks, but like I said that doesn't solve my problem `arecord -d 10 -f S16_LE -r 16000 test.wav`should work without specifing any devices and only then maybe I can get a wake word engine to work

Comment: `arecord` without specifying a device will try to use the default device. The default device will be whatever you have set in your `/etc/asound.conf` or `~/.asoundrc`.

Comment: See updated answer with the dtparam setting. I know on archlinux i had trouble with audio until I set that.